# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, regarding X11"

Tags: c++, macos, linker, x11, x86-64

I am compiling and linking a command-line application on a 64-bit Mac platform, using g++.

The OS is OSX 10.9.4, and I am using the IDE Eclipse Luna for C/C++.

At the linker-stage, the error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" is thrown.

Various references from the X11 package are then shown.

I am indeed linking with :

```
g++ -L/opt/X11/lib -o <output> <input objects>
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The problem was as follows:  It was a command-line application, not utilising the GUI portion of the X11 suite.  I removed the link to any GUI-related code from my application, and the linker was happy.